# Program not detecting collision with Physics Body SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift4

I have a simple game where meteors are spawned and the player must dodge these meteors. I am trying to detect if the player (rocketship) has collided with the meteor (enemy) with PhysicsBody. However, nothing happens when they collide. The console should print "Crash detected"
Here's my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceship")
    let stars = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "stars")
    let meteor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "meteor")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print(frame.size.width)
        print(frame.size.height)

        stars.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
        stars.zPosition = 1
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width / 2)

        player.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:-320)
        player.zPosition = 4
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1



        self.addChild(player)
        self.addChild(stars)

        addMeteor()


    }



    func addMeteor() {
        meteor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: meteor.size.width / 2)
        meteor.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        meteor.setScale(0.50)
        meteor.position = CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%300),y:Int(arc4random()%600))
        //meteor.position = CGPoint(x:0 , y:0)
        meteor.zPosition = 4

        meteor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        meteor.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        self.addChild(meteor)
    }

    func fireBullet() {
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.position = player.position
        bullet.setScale(0.5)
        bullet.zPosition = 3
        self.addChild(bullet)

        let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
        let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
        bullet.run(bulletSequence)


    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        fireBullet()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch:  AnyObject in touches {
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x
            player.position.x += amountDragged
        }

    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("Crash detected")
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        meteor.position.y -= 6
        if meteor.position.y < player.position.y - 300{
            meteor.removeFromParent()
            addMeteor()

        }
        }
    }
```

The program should detect collision and then execute the didBegin function (which prints "Crash detected" to the console). However, when I run the program, the console doesn't have anything printed to it. Anybody know what im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: in **didMove** method add ***physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self*** this line of code and set your meteor a contactTestBitMask like so: **meteor.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask**

Comment: @ImrulKayes make that an answer to get rep, also he needs to give his player a category, 0 means nothing can hit him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in didMove method add this line of code ***physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self***. you set playerCateoryBitmask to 0. that means nothing can hit the player. use **player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2** and also set your meteor a contactTestBitMask like so: **meteor.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask**

Comment: @Imrual Kayes what value should I give meteor.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask

Comment: @sirishaGaddipati, use ***meteor.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2***

Comment: it didn't work? Meteor simply goes over the ship and nothing is printed to console?

Comment: @sirishaGaddipati, you have set players Physicsbody twice. Did you notice that? code should work properly, read thoroughly.

Comment: @ImrulKayes work on your answer a bit, clean it up and explain the parts to help teach the poster how to properly used the physics engine.

Comment: @ImrulKayes sorry about that, it works now. My fault for not reading the answer thoroughly